# initialize counter value to 0 in prometheus

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-java

I'm using a simple client Prometheus version 0.6.0

I have a set of counters that are defined this way

```
private static final Counter CD_PRODUCT_SUCCESS_CREATED = new  Counter.Builder()
            .name("cd_Product_success_created")
            .help("product success created.")
            .labelNames("podname")
            .create()
            .register(CollectorRegistry.defaultRegistry);
....
```

```
 public List<MetricFamilySamples> collect() {
        List<MetricFamilySamples> samples = new ArrayList<>();
        samples.addAll(CD_PRODUCT_SUCCESS_CREATED.collect());
        ....
        return samples;
```

```
public void addCdProductSuccessCreated() {
        CD_PRODUCT_SUCCESS_CREATED.labels(podName).inc();
    }
```

I inject this class in places where I need it and then call the methods like addCdProductSuccessCreated() yet for the metrics that do not have values they look empty when I **scrape** them ex:

```
# HELP cd_Product_success_created
# TYPE cd_Product_success_created counter
```

my question is how can I initilize the counter with the value 0 so that it appears even tho the inc method is not called

Comment: See [Existential issues with metrics](https://www.robustperception.io/existential-issues-with-metrics). You should able to initialize to zero by proceeding as if you were `inc`'ing or `set`'ting the metric value **but** exclude the `inc` or `set`

Comment: checked the article you posted I couldn't quite get the answer should I add a static block  static {
     counter.labels("podname");
     ...
  } like this  ?

Comment: I'm not a Java developer. The example appears to match what you're doing and that should give you a zeroed `counter` so that the metric appears in the exporter and you can include it in PromQL. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 3):

found the answer I did add a block like this

```
static { CD_PRODUCT_SUCCESS_CREATED .labels("podname"); ... }
```

for all the metrics and now I could see the 0.0 value for the metrics